# Percolation clustering

Tags: r

Consider the following groupings:

```
> data.frame(x = c(3:5,7:9,12:14), grp = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3))
   x grp
1  3   1
2  4   1
3  5   1
4  7   2
5  8   2
6  9   2
7 12   3
8 13   3
9 14   3
```

Let's say I don't know the `grp` values but only have a vector `x`.  What is the easiest way to generate `grp` values, essentially an id field of groups of values within a threshold from from each other?  Is this a percolation algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to compare the next with the current value and check if the difference is greater than 1, and get the cumulative sum.

```
 df1$grp <- cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(df1$x) > 1))
 df1$grp
 #[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

EDIT: From @geotheory's comments.

Comment: @geotheory Isn't this the same as your expected output in 'grp'.  If not, you have to create a new example.

Comment: Hmm close but not a general solution: try for `x = c(7:9,12:14,3:5)`

Comment: @geotheory YOu have to update your post because I was using your example for coding this.

Comment: @geotheory For your new example `cumsum(c(TRUE, (x[-1] - x[-length(x)]) != 1))`

Comment: @geotheory What is the expected output for the `x`?  I get the same 1 to 3

Comment: Actually I'm totally mistaken. Yours is a general solution - thanks for help :)  I still haven't got my head around how it works though!

Comment: the general threshold solution is `cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(df1$x) > 1))`

Comment: @geotheory The `diff` gets the difference between adjacent elements and give an output of length one less than the original vector.  We check whether the difference is not equal to 1 to get the logical vector.  Concatenate with `TRUE` at the beginning to adjust the length and then do the cumsum.

Comment: That's insane. Do you think in binary?

Comment: Cumulative summing of logical vectors.  It's a Brave New World out there.. cheers

Comment: @geotheory Thanks for the comments.  I might have solved a similar question before.